# When updating a model on a RESTful API, should there be an update endpoint per field? or one endpoint for the model?

Tags: architecture, database, rest, api, backend

For a RESTful API, consider a model schema as follows:

```
MyCoolObject {
  field_a
  field_b
  field_c
}
```

Is it better to **create one** update endpoint to update one or many fields on the model? Or **create one endpoint per field** that would only update that one field?

Comment: Is there some reason why someone would want to update this object one field at a time? That just sounds bizarre to me.

Comment: @JohnWu, one field at a time is an exaggerration, but in a scenario where your model is very large and you wanted to minimize over-the-wire costs, requests containing the whole object could get expensive

Comment: Maybe it would be a better idea to avoid very large models.

Comment: Easier said than done hahaha

Answer (score 1):

There is no one answer for this question. It really depends on how the underlying object changes, what kind of business rules or process you have around the change, etc etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use the same endpoint, but use HTTP PUT to update the entire model and use PATCH to update one or more individual fields.